# professional android app look&feel, xml made or phonegap?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

i just wanted to ask you guys a question... i've been making a research about android UI layouts... but as i've been trying to simulate Instagram or facebook's UI, it's hard. For example, that type of fancy button in the bottom of Instagram's app.

Is this being done with phonegap which is javascript/jquery, CSS and HTML (and then compiled for Android) or directly being done with android layouts?

What i mean with this is, is it possible to make that kind of job with Android native XML layout? also, those pipe lines to separate the button in the header/bottom like:

SETTINGS ICON | HOME ICON | etc ...

With the little white shading, how it's done? is it an IMG? :S

Comment: It is possible, you can use either images, or built in effects, but most of them use images with fancy transparency and other stuff.

Comment: mmm i see, i've tried doing that and my images were some sort of bad quality :S saved them as .png made in photoshop, nice resolution for icons, but whenever i put them in my app, it looks kinda "pixelized". I got a Galaxy S2 btw. The images looks a bit blurry. Why is that happening? @MarkoLazić

Comment: Since mobile has varying screen size and pixel ratio across devices, you could use svg image or really big image and scale it down.  Or a common way to do it is with css media query like: @media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)

Comment: @Noogen Thanks for the data man :) i will try to do that. The SVG option was nice too or a bit large one... let's say 128x128 instead of 32x32 for icons? and then shrink them.